# How do you join several input wires into one wire in systemverilog (all wires except one hi-Z)

Tags: system-verilog

Suppose that all input wires except one is supposed to be in Hi-Z. We want to connect these wires into a single wire (e.g. data bus). How can this be done in SystemVerilog?

Comment: What do you want the output to be? What if there is a also a zero? Should it be synthesize?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean module inputs, the `alias` construct can do this:

`module a(input wire a,b,c);
  wire bus; // use if you want a different internal name 
  alias a = b = c = bus;
endmodule`

I'm sure this will not be synthesizable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your condition that only one input is not Z holds true then we could just loop through and find the last non-Z input and assign its value to the output. No idea if this would synthesize.

```
module merge_bus
  #(parameter BUSW = 8)
  (
   input [BUSW-1:0] bus_in,
   output wire_out
  );

  always_comb begin
    wire_out = 1'bz;
    for(int i = 0; i<BUSW; i++) begin
      if(bus_in[i] !== 1'bz) wire_out = bus_in[i];
    end
  end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of wor/wand data types from verilog.